# Error When Using Make

Tags: objective-c, makefile, gnustep

I'm learning Objective-C using GNUStep in my Windows(Cygwin) and i have two files, one source and one make file:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

APP_NAME = HelloWorld
HelloWorld_HEADERS = 
HelloWorld_OBJC_FILES = main.m
HelloWorld_RESOURCE_FILES =

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/application.make
```

But when i run make in the directory i'm getting this errors:

```
GNUmakefile:1: /common.make: No such file or directory
GNUmakefile:8: /application.make: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/application.make'.  Stop.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES variable needs to be set to point to the directory
that has that commmon.make file in it.
K

Comment: How can i set it? because i'm a C/C++ developer, but i don't like to use makefiles, now i'm needing to learn. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that i know here are this files.

Comment: First, locate that common.make file.  Once you know where that is, you can edit the makefile and put something like
GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES=/path/name up at the top before the variable is used, or you can set an environment variable(export GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES=/path/name) before invoking make.  Here is a link to a make tutorial that should get you started with make:
http://frank.mtsu.edu/~csdept/FacilitiesAndResources/make.htm
K

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the value of the `GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES` variable. You have two ways to achieve this:

1. Use an environment variable: `export GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES=/the/path/you/want`.
2. Set it directly in the `Makefile`: put a line `GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES = /the/path/you/want` in the `Makefile` somewhere before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Debian Linux provides `/usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh` script that sets and exports all the appropriate `GNUSTEP_*` environment variables. Perhaps there is something similar in your Windows GNUstep distribution package?

Comment: That script is a part of GNUstep-make package.